# Is there a way to split an SQL command into it's parts?

Tags: php, sql

ie:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE blah JOIN test AS t2 ON (table.id = test.id) GROUP BY user ORDER BY id

into:

```
[
    "SELECT" => "*",
    "FROM" => ["table" => "table", "AS" => "table"],
    "WHERE" => "blah",
    "JOIN" => ["table" => "test", "AS" => "t2", "ON" => "(table.id = test.id)"],
    "GROUP BY" => "user",
    "ORDER BY" => ["field" => "id", "order" => "ASC"],
]
```

Is there a way to get how MYSQLI/PHP sees it, or would I have to make a parser myself which isn't guaranteed to parse it the same way

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure this is not an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

The term you are searching for is `Tokenize`, and a quick search with the right terms brings up:
https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser (PHP)
https://github.com/fibo/SQL-tokenizer (JavaScript)
https://github.com/klahnakoski/mo-sql-parsing (Python)
https://github.com/hyrise/sql-parser (C++)

Although, it might not be exactly what you want, and you could end up rewriting some parts.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping PHP/MYSQLI had a way of getting what it parsed before execution. But thinking about it now, that's done on the SQL server, not the PHP server...

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Okay! Although, the first link above is `MySQL` parser written in `PHP`, but I hope you found an even better solution (still, maybe accept the answer to help others searching for the same)